# How to open Android studio without terminal on Linux 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android

i am using Linux 16.04. How to launch Android Studio IDE without using terminal?

Comment: And I thought I was up-to-date by using a 4.x series Linux kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named `AndroidStudio.desktop` wherever you want to be able to launch AS from. Paste the following inside it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android Studio
Exec=/path/to/install/studio.sh
Path=/path/to/install/
Icon=/path/to/launcher/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Development;
```

Obviously, modify the `Exec`, `Path` and `Icon` fields to reflect the proper paths.

Comment: It is showing "There was an error launching the application"

Comment: You're gonna have to give more details.

Comment: What is here path to install? Is it the same path to studio.sh?

Comment: While double clicking the file pops up a dialog box saying 'There was an error launching the application.'

Comment: @CecilPaul it's the path to the directory containing studio.sh.